# unix ls modified today with full iso

Tags: unix, ls

I have found the following command that meets all my requirements bar one. I need the output time style to be full iso. What do I need to change to make this happen?

```
ls -al --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D)
```

Comment: `ls -al --time-style=full-iso | grep $(date --iso-8601)`?

Comment: @vanza Please, consider adding your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the time format in your own command:

```
ls -al --time-style=full-iso | grep $(date --iso-8601)
```